# Python program that simulates rolling a 6 sided die and adds up the result of each roll till you roll a 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, probability, dice

so this is the code I wrote that attempts to answer the question in the title :

```
import random
print("Well, hello there.")
while True:
    a = random.randint(1,6)
    sum = 0
    if(a==1): #If a one is indeed rolled, it just shows rolled a 1 and 'Pigs out' and makes the score equal to 0(player score that is) and is a sort of a GameOver
        print("Pigged out!")
        break #To get out of the loop
    else:
        while(sum<=20): 
            sum += a
            print(sum)
```

The program should hold the score till it reaches 20(or more) and display it. It essentially represents a single turn of 'Pig'. I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong with this? Any suggestions would be helpful.

An example of a sample output:

`-rolled a 6
-rolled a 6
-rolled a 5
-rolled a 6
-Turn score is 23`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand rightly then you can simplify this quite a lot, like this:

```
import random
print("Well, hello there.")
score = 0
while score < 20:
    a = random.randint(1,6)
    print("A {} was rolled".format(a))
    score += a
    if a == 1:
        print("Pigged out!")
        score = 0
        break
print("Turn score is {}".format(score))
```

Comment: Yes this works too! I love how simple and straightforward this is! Still learning how to simplify code as I am a beginner. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the sum once it's greater than 20, shouldn't you unindent the `print(sum)` to the left? Essentially:

```
while(sum<=20): 
    sum += a
print(sum)
```

It would be nice if you could clarify what you want the output to be and what it is currently doing.

Comment: It should roll till the sum is 20 or more and just display it. Now my program is rolling a lot of non-1s and just goes on until a 1 is rolled. How do I make it stop when the sum is 20?

Answer (score 0):

You should break after the sum is more than 20

```
else:
    while(sum<=20): 
        sum += a
        print(sum)
    break
```

Edit:

```
import random
print("Well, hello there.")
while True:
    a = random.randint(1,6)
    sum = 0
    if(a==1): #If a one is indeed rolled, it just shows rolled a 1 and 'Pigs out' and makes the score equal to 0(player score that is) and is a sort of a GameOver
        print("Pigged out!")
        break #To get out of the loop
    else:
        if not SumWasReached:
           while(sum<=20): 
               a = random.randint(1,6)
               sum += a
               print(sum)
           SumWasReached ==True:
        else:
            while(a!=1):
               a = random.randint(1,6)
            break
```

Comment: Alright I tried indenting the code and adding the break statement and it works but it is rolling the same dice value? Like it displays rolled a 4 5 times or rolled a 6 4 times and shows the score. Is it some error or just 'random'?

Comment: It is rolling the numbers all over again because a = random.randint(1,6) was set outside the loop. So it doesn't dice again

Comment: @user285347 Thanks! Finally figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
import random
print("Well, hello there.")
sum=0
while True:
    a = random.randint(1,6)
    sum+=a
    if(a==1): #If a one is indeed rolled, it just shows rolled a 1 and 'Pigs out' and makes the score equal to 0(player score that is) and is a sort of a GameOver
        print("Pigged out!")
        break #To get out of the loop
    else:
        if sum<=20: 
            sum += a
            print(sum)
        else:
            print(sum,'limit reached')
            break
```

Comment: The output should be something like `-rolled a 6 -rolled a 4` so on until the score is 20 or more at which point it should stop. If a 1 is rolled, the score becomes 0(game over).I added a print("- rolled a " + str(a)) to show the user what they rolled.